# Is it possible to configure a UITableView to allow multiple-selection?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, multiple-select

For the iPhone, is it possible to configure a UITableView such that it will allow multiple-selection?

I've tried overriding `-setSelected:animated:` for each UITableViewCell, but trying to fudge the required behavior is tricky as it's difficult to separate the real unselections from the ones where the UITableView thinks I've unselected due to selection of another cell!

Hope someone can help!

Thanks,

Nick.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to a checkmark per selected row.

You can do that by setting the accessoryType on the selected UITableViewCell instances to UITableViewCelAccessoryCheckmark.

To deselect the row, set it back to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone.

To enumerate which cells/rows were selected (say, upon clicking a button), simply iterate over the cells of the table looking for UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.  Or, manage some NSSet or the like in your table view delegate in the "did select" delegate methods.

Comment: There's a nice example of using the "did select" delegate methods to keep track of the selected cells/rows here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985907/iphone-how-to-allow-multiple-selection-in-tabelview-for-a-custom-cell)

Comment: Iterating over the cells of the table isn't accurate since table cells are often recycled and reused as you scroll through your table.

Answer (score 40):

Following property should work fine if you are developing app for iOS5.0+

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Comment: this is the standard iOS way of handling multiple selections in a tableView. see also Apple's sample https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @JonEasy not at the time when the question was asked.

Answer (score 25):

Use the following code to set up the cell accesory types:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }else{
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
}

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//add your own code to set the cell accesory type.
return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: While compiling under iOS 4.x the following warning is received:  WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <MyViewController: 0x6e4fca0>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release. FYI.

Answer (score 24):

Jeff Lamarche has a tutorial on how to do this here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html

I've not tried the code but it's been on the back of my mind for a while, knowing the day will come when I need it.

Answer (score 11):

I backported `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` and `allowsMultipleSelection` from iOS5 to older iOS. You can fork it at https://github.com/ud7/UDTableView-allowsMultipleSelection

It's drop in replacement and only thing you need to do is change UITableView to UDTableView (in code or interface builder)

Answer (score 5):

From the HIG:

> Table views provide feedback when users select list items. Specifically, when an item can be selected, the 
>   row containing the item highlights briefly when a user selects it to show that the selection has been received. 
>   Then, an immediate action occurs: Either a new view is revealed or the row displays a checkmark to indicate 
>   that the item has been selected. The row never remains highlighted, because table views do not display a 
>   persistent selected state.

You'll need to roll your own multiple selection style, either with something like Mail, or using the checkmark accessory on your cells.

Answer (score 5):

Guys for multiple selection you just need

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

on viewDidLoad and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO; 
    // if you don't use custom image tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    // if you don't use custom image tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for the same issue and the answer of Bhavin Chitroda sovled it for me but with some addition to keep the check mark as it was while scrolling.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ( [array indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound ) {
            [array addObject:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            [array removeObject:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

}
```

The addition:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
// Your code here
.
.
.
    if ( [array indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound ) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do something like Mail's multiple-select (to delete mail, for example), then you're probably going to have to manage all the selection yourself. Multiple row selection isn't something that's standard on the iPhone. Mail solves this by using checkmarks to indicate which rows have been selected.

Answer (score 2):

blue highlighted row as an indicator of whether a row is selected is actually discouraged according to the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf) page 121. Checkmarks will do the trick.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    cout << "selected Row: " << selectedRow << endl;
    UITableViewCell *indexPathForCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPathForCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        indexPathForCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        indexPathForCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

}
```

then add your arraying or how ever you wish to store the data of which were selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This does not work in iOS 4+.  This is a private, undocumented constant.  Do not use it.**

If you are not planning to submit your app to the App Store, you can invoke multi-row edit mode by implementing the following method in your UITableViewController delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 3; // Undocumented constant
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully!  Why oh why isn't this documented and allowed?!!  Has anyone gotten an app approved with this in it?  Not calling any undocumented methods... ?

Comment: Yeah what a bummer that this is still a private API.  So SO useful.

Comment: apparently it is not anymore on 4.x---

Comment: To clarify: this doesn't seem to work anymore under iOS4 from my testing (I wasn't sure if Digital Robot was saying that it wasn't private or had been disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with iOS4.3 - 6.0

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

    if ([controller.searchResultsTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing)]) {
        controller.searchResultsTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    }
    else {
        controller.searchResultsTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```