# UITableView allow two cells to have selected style at the same time

Tags: iphone, uitableview, templates, selection, cell

I have created a UItableView using the default Xcode template and configure it to display five rows.
I select the first cell on the table. When I select another cell I notice the first one stay selected until I remove my finger from the second one.

sample:
http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7184/cellsz.jpg

I want a cell to become selected on touch not on touch remove.
I searched on the net and in apple documentation but I didn't find which method is called when the user touch the screen for selection.

Does anyone have some information about this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-confugure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have succeeded in suppressing this double selection effect.

A cell becomes selected when the system detect a touch up inside event on it.
Before it becomes selected, the cell have a highlight state which appear on touch.

To resolve this issue I have to override the `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated` method in my custom UITableViewCell and do nothing in this method.

This way the table will never have two selected style cells at the same time.

quote after edit

> This solution is enought for me, but
>   it doesn't resolve my first request to
>   change cell's selection on "touch in"
>   event instead of "touch out" event.

well... I assume this is impossible. If we had this option we could select a cell when we just wanted to scroll in a tableview.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know answer on your question, but have an offer. You can mark selected row with the checkmark in your

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method. And then call `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

Comment: well... I wasn't clear enought. I apologize.
actually in my case there is always one selected cell.
the problem is if a cell is selected the second one will have the selected style on touch but it won't be selected.

I have already tried this method but didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called when you remove the finger from the cell not when you touch the cell and stay on it.

I added a screen shot to show how it looks like.
http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7184/cellsz.jpg

Comment: I mean that if you only have to mark selected row, you can change its accessoryType to, for example, UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeCheckmark and call deselectRow in that delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

There's no framework provided solution to select multiple rows. Morion has a good way to do this with checkmarks. You can also look at [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html) article by Matt Gallagher where his implements what you wants.

Comment: I don't want multiple cell selection. I wasn't clear I apologize.
I want to avoid two cell to have the selected style at the same time. this gives application a real bad look.
look at the screenshot I added in my post.