# Emulating iPhone and iPod Touch Inbox Edit Mode (Red Check Marks, Blue Background)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can one emulate the UITableViewCell(s) used when bulk editing (All Inboxes > Edit) in the Mail App. Specifically, the hollow circles that fill with a red filling and white checkmark when selected (and the cell also changes to a blue tint). Is it possible do this with existing disclosure? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method for selecting editing style return 3. This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! Do you happen to know why this isn't documented or featured as an enumerable constant? Cheers!

Comment: it is enumerated. I just couldnt remember it at the time. Its called UITableCellAccessoryCheckmark so you can return that instead of 3. As to why its not documented I have no idea. From my experience Apple to loves to stick you into their little box of what you can and cant do. I find it infuriating that these such features exist and Apple doesnt document it for us developers.

Comment: Does this still work? Another question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection says it doesn't work in iOS4+ and was private anyway, preventing app store submission.