# Select multiple rows in UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to select multiple rows in a UITableview just like Apple does in the native Alarm app (see picture [image]

How can I do that?

All the answers I saw so far were old (and said "Can't do") or refer to the multiple row selection in the native Mail app. That method is not what I would like because you have to enter in the "edit"-mode first. I want to be able to select the rows right away.

Hope someone can help.

Christian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

do

```
    if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
       [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else{
       [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
```

Edit:

You also have to use an array that maps the checked cells and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you have to verify if the accessoryType should be checked or not.

Comment: You should never store checked status in table cells themselves - they may be reused for multiple rows when table scrolls and you'll need to restore checked state somehow...

Comment: I also have an array that maps the checked cells and in cell for row at index path I verify if the accessoryType should be checked or not

Answer (score 31):

Easiest way i've found:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

You can see which cells are selected by calling:

```
NSArray *selectedCells = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome.. +1 but i had a slight problem.. How to get value from the NSArray. If you could please edit your answer Thanks

Comment: I like your solution, but it seems if I select a cell, multiple cells get selected, with a gap of approximately screen height.
I will use an array to store the checked status for each cell now.

Answer (score 12):

Play with

`tableView.allowsMultipleSelection`

This saved me hours of trouble. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9969185/385559).

Comment: Isn't this `allowsMultipleSelection`?

Comment: Yes, it is allowsMultipleSelection, not allowsMultipleAnswersAccepted

Answer (score 8):

"Selected" rows in Clock application are cells with `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` accessory type.

Possible steps to achieve that are:

1. Store checked/not checked state somewhere for each row.
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method for cell in checked row set cell's `accessoryType` property to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`
3. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for cell in not checked row set cell's `accessoryType` property to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`
4. When cell is selected (tapped) deselect it, invert its checked status and reload cell at that index path

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Storyboards, just click on the Table View and then on the Attributes Inspector on the right hand panel, set the "selection" property to "Multiple Selection".  I've verified this using Xcode version 8.2.1.