# Selecting multiple objects at tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using table view for selecting objects. I want to select muliple objects in a tableview. I am using following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: ContactCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier) as! ContactCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    let person=contacts[row]
    cell.setCell(person.nameLabel,image: "")
    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let person=contacts[row]

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

My tableview looks like this:

[image]

I selected the "Kate" then I scroll down to bottom and "Test" is marked too. But why? I selected just "Kate". How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please follow the link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616345/select-multiple-rows-in-uitableview][1]. Its a perfect answer (Y)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616345/select-multiple-rows-in-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is selected "too", because inside a UITableView cells are reused...

```
let cell: ContactCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier) as! ContactCell
```

If you want to solve this problem, the best way would be to save each cells state inside the array, which is holding your data of the UITableView... This is the best way.

Another way would be to declare a Dictionary of type [Int: Bool] and save your selected states to this... the Int key would be the row index, and its value could be true for selected, or false for not...

**UPDATE**

Following an example on how to solve your problem

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactsTableView: UITableView!
    lazy var contactsArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    //This method is to convert your contacts string array, into the array you need
    private func appendContactsToContactsArray (contacts: [String]) {
        for contact in contacts {
            contactsArray.append(["name": contact, "selected": false])
        }
        contactsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contactsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: ContactCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ContactCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = contactsArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

        if (isCellSelectedAtIndexPath(indexPath)) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (isCellSelectedAtIndexPath(indexPath)) {
            contactsArray[indexPath.row]["selected"] = false
        } else {
            contactsArray[indexPath.row]["selected"] = true
        }
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

    private func isCellSelectedAtIndexPath (indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return contactsArray[indexPath.row]["selected"] as? Bool ?? false
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give little example about saving to array?

Comment: Sure... But you may have to change the way of storing your contacts inside your array... Currently it looks like its a string array, you need an array of dictionarys... but I will write you a func which will solve this too

Comment: Thank you so much, i am waiting.

Comment: I tried it now: fatal error: Array index out of range for return contactsArray[indexPath.row]["selected"] as? Bool ?? false how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this effect because cells are cached and reused.  Note the word "Reusable" in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Make "selected" a property of a contact or person.  Set it true or false when a row is selected or deselected.  Reload your data and set the accessory type in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Could you give an example for this?