# Tableview with 2 section

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Hello
I am developing an app which is using a tableview with two sections(instead of radio buttons).
So I want these section to act like radio buttons. To accomplish this, I have to implement an "if" in the 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

I want to use something like: if (section == "A"). 
How to do that?
Also is this the right way to make the sections of a table acting like a different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... that sounds like an odd set up, but irrespective, you simply use the provided `indexPath` to obtain the section/row.

i.e.: `indexPath.section` will point to the selected section and `indexPath.row` will point to the row.

For more information, the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW10) is a good start as it covers all of the above in quite a bit of detail.

**UPDATE**

In terms of highlighting multiple cells, I'd have thought that you'd want to create your own concept of highlighting, which you'd toggle on and off when the user selects the cell.

That said, you could also mark selected cells via the `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` as per the existing [Is it possible to configure a UITableView to allow multiple-selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection) question/answer.

Comment: ok guys thank you both. ANyone knows how to allow 2 cells to be highlighted at the same time?

Comment: @user622203 I've updated my answer with a potentially useful existing question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "section to act like radio buttons" but to distinguish between sections in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` use `indexPath.section`:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    // first section
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    // second section
}
```

Comment: ok guys thank you both. ANyone knows how to allow 2 cells to be highlighted at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you must need to use `indexPath.section:` to distinguish between your table sections

So your code should be like below .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
{
   if (indexPath.section == 0)
   {
     //first section
   }
   else if (indexPath.section == 1)
   {
     //second section
   }
}
```