# How to make multiple select in a tableview cell by using checkmark in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have a class in which I have a tableview and in the tableview I am display the values through array. When I run my application and select the cell of tableview only one particular cell gets selected at a time and its value is displayed in the detailtextlabel of my previous controller. I want that multiple selects should be enabled at a time.

Right now I am doing this. This is the class where I want that my multiple tableview cell should get selected:

TAddAlarmNewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    days =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Every Monday",@"Every Tuesday",@"Every Wednesday",@"Every Thursday",@"Every Friday",@"Every Saturday",@"Every Sunday",nil];
    temp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:days,@"arrValue",nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

In the days array I am storing 7 values, and in the no of rowinsection I am counting the array:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [days count];
}
```

and in the cellforrowatindexpath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = ([indexPath isEqual:rowselection]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}
```

In this I am adding my arrays to the textlabel of my cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //rowselection is an indexpath variable.
     self.rowselection = indexPath;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];
    for (int  i=0; i<[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]; i++) 
    {
        UIViewController *aController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([aController isKindOfClass:[TAddAlarmController class]])
        {

            TAddAlarmController *addalarm = (TAddAlarmController*)aController;
            newrepeat =(NSString*)[[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
            [addalarm refreshTableToSetDetailText:newrepeat];
        }
    }

//TAddAlarmController is the previous controller in which detailtextlabel i am setting the next controller value.
}
```

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection

Comment: @vijay, 1 upvote for good link.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Vijay solves ur problem. Also u need to keep an array (with bool values) to maintain whether a row is selected or not. So while reloading the table view, u can put the checkmarks correctly.

Comment: yes she is right u have to keep track that because cell is autoreleased object.so while again creation of ur old selected cell it has to get selected.

Comment: No, I am not talking about datasource array. Declare new array. U know the size of the datasource array. (Might be 7 here). Add 7 NSNumber objects , all with NO , to the array. Whenever a row is selected, toggle the value at the index in the array.

Comment: Gomathi i am totally confused whether i have create 2 array or single array to hold the bool value and then how to display my array which contains that sunday,monday,tuesday on tableview cell.please can u provide some dummy code or can u change in my code itself what u want to say.Please

Comment: Gomathi ya multiple select is possible now

Comment: But their exist a problem the multiple selected row values is not displayed in my detailtextlabel of my tableview controller.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    CustomViewCell* theCell = (CustomViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    theCell.mySelectedImage.hidden = NO;

    //[tableView reloadData];
    [selectedIndices insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] atIndex:arrayIndex]; //the selectedIndices is array that stores index of selected rows
    NSLog(@"%@",[selectedIndices objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]);
    arrayIndex++;

    [tableView reloadData]; 
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomViewCell  *cell = (CustomViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell =  [[[CustomViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.mySelectedImage.hidden = YES;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    // this loop will check for selected index when table gets reload 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [selectedIndices count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[selectedIndices objectAtIndex:i]);

        int t = indexPath.row;
        int ind = [[selectedIndices objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        if (t == ind) 
        {
            cell.mySelectedImage.hidden = NO;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```