# iPhone: How to allow multiple selection in tabelview for a custom cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

How can I adapt this to be able to make multiple selections? and get the selected ones

```
- (id)initWithCellIdentifier:(NSString *)cellID {
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID])) {

    UITableViewCell *cell=self; 
            UIImage *cry = [UIImage APP_CRYSTAL_SELECT];
    self.leftImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cry] autorelease] ;
            [self.contentView addSubview:leftImage];            
}
```

And the selected method is:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
      if(selected)
      {
       NSArray *subviews=[self.contentView subviews];
        for(UIView* view in subviews){
          if([view isEqual:self.leftImage]){
             [self.leftImage setHighlightedImage:[UIImage APP_CRYSTAL_SELECTED]];
        }
    }
}
else
{       
    NSArray *subviews=[self.contentView subviews];
    for(UIView* view in subviews){
        if([view isEqual:self.leftImage]){
            [self.leftImage setHighlightedImage:[UIImage APP_CRYSTAL_SELECT]];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For multiple selection, setup an NSMutableArray ivar (selectedIndexPaths in this case) to hold the items that are selected. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add or remove indexPaths to this array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
        if(![self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
            [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        else
            [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

Use selectedIndexPaths later to do whatever you wish! Cheers!

-Akshay

Comment: Customcell subclass's setselected method gets called before selectedIndexPaths in the tableview, but I want to implement the functionality in the tableview class?

Comment: That does not matter. Just implement whatever you wish to in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (which is in the table view class). setSelected can be kept for updating the UI due to the selection/deselection.

Comment: but cause it gets called later, the UI is already updated, and not much left to do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Akshay see if you can figure this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126654/cells-lose-memory-of-selection-unsolved-issue