# UITableView Grouped - Select multiple rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView and want to select some rows.
Hers some handy code I found to select multiple rows but for a ungrouped view.

--->

When I'm selecting a row it selects this row of every section.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}}
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At happens as soon as you select a row or after you reload your table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at - [iPhone: How to allow multiple selection in tabelview for a custom cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985907/iphone-how-to-allow-multiple-selection-in-tabelview-for-a-custom-cell/6991289#6991289). If you just set the accessory type as you have done in your code, the accessories won't be maintained when the cells are recycled (when the table is scrolled). Instead you should do something like the following-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //... your existing code ...
    if(self.selectedIndexPaths && [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) //selectedIndexPaths is explained in the link above
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    //... your existing code ...
    return cell;
}
```

This way, you can maintain which cells are selected.

HTH,

Akshay

Answer (score 0):

i think you have taken multiple tables in on view for this differentiate tableviews like

```
if(tableView = firstTbl){


}
if(tableView = secondTbl){


}
```

Comment: no, no i have it like this -> http://cocoaheads.be/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Default_Grouped_TableView.png