# Saving the state of my UITable View

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have a checklist that is on a UITable View. The user can add/delete cells and check them and uncheck them. I need some assistance with saving the state of the checklist when the page is left, becuase when the user adds a new cell, leaves the page, and returns, the table view is back in the original state i had made it be in! Does someone know my problem? Thanks Guys :D
-Kurt

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024392/uitableview-grouped-select-multiple-rows/7025152#7025152. Let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: right. this is for a checklist right? I want to save the checklist when the page is left. like when cells are deleted or added, i want it to be the exact same way when the person comes back to the page?

Comment: If you want to restore the checkmarks across app launches, you will have to save the information using CoreData, etc. If the maximum lifetime of your checkmarks is the app's lifetime, an instance variable should do.

Comment: dang... ok do you know where i should start to learn core data? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Go to google.com. Type "coredata". Click on the 2nd link.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be missing is that adding or deleting a row from your table does not update your source array. Typically when working with a UITableview there are three steps you must perform:

1. add or remove the tableview cell
2. update your source array (presumably adding or deleting objects in your context)
3. save your context to commit the changes

This is assuming you are using Core Data for persistent store. If you are saving in memory than you are likely done at step 2.

I suggest you review the UITableView Class reference, look over the examples and step through a tutorial before trying to stumble through the process.

Comment: how could you save a UITableView in memory? Thanks for the help bud!

Comment: You don't save the table view. You save the source and state so you can redisplay on return.

Comment: oh, wow.. okay! What would you reccommend to be a good way to save the source? Mine is an array. Do you think it would be easier to learn core data? Or is there a more simple Way? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I came from a background of mdb and sql databases. Core Data, at first, seemed completely foreign to me. I suggest you jump right in and try something. Go to iTunes U and follow a tutorial or class. Once you get it, it becomes very easy.