# Multirow select and delete in UITableView in iphone like Mail app in iphone

Tags: ios, ios-4.2, ios4

I came across few blogs which tell how to do this, but I'm not sure if apple will accept or reject the apps. The links which i gone through are below:

- [Multiple row selection and editing in a UITableView](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html)
- [Multiple Row Selection with UITableView — The Easy Way](http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/07/multiple-row-selection-with-uitableview.html)

Please friends can you help me out with simple solution regarding how can this be done?

I came to know that there is a delegate function for this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 3;
}
```

But how to implement this and how can I select the specific rows with checkmark as it's done in standard mail app from apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documentation for the `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` property in a UITableView (only available starting iOS 5).

Also, look at this question:
[Is it possible to configure a UITableView to allow multiple-selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection)

A guy in there backported the functionality to older iOS: https://github.com/ud7/UDTableView-allowsMultipleSelection