# How to enable a multi-select in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii every body i have a tableview with some datas in it,i want to to sync it with googledoc ,my need is the user can select multiple selection in tableview cell and export those note to Gdoc.So is there any method for multiple selection in tableview with a tickmark or check mark? .Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    else {

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }
```

we have to set the property for selectedindexpath in.h

```
@property (retain) NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath;
```

Thanks.