# How to quick select all rows in iOS5 UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios5

With iOS-5 UITableView allowsmultipleselection, is there any quick way with good performance to select (and highlighted) all rows? I'm talking about more than thousands rows data of fetchedResultsController.

I've tried with selectRowAtIndexPath:animated loop, and seems it's not a good idea for huge dataset.

Also I've discovered if deselect all rows performance will be better with tableview reloadData than deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: inside a loop. Is this the safe way to clear selections?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection

Comment: Someone else had a similar question recently, but I'm not managing to find the link. His problem was solved by sidestepping the selection issue -- if there's something you want to do to all rows, it might make more sense to have a button for it (e.g. "Delete All").

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you haven't any other posibility to select rows, only `selectRowAtIndexPath:`.

And I think, you shouldn't have so many rows in table view, try to optimize it. Do you really need so many rows?

Comment: Having so many rows is fine. UITableView was designed to work with a huge number of rows.

Comment: I agree. But row selection is not agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i had several cells already not created. And i had to select them all.
But you can not reach a cell not created. So i couldn't use getTableViewCellForRowAtIndex: function.

I had a solution for selected entities, i set the whole collection as selectedcollection.
But my problem was on UI, i had to show them to the user.

So i decided to create a checkedXXXTableViewCell, and inherited this class from XXXTableViewCell. (They exactly use the same business) 
And i made the check button (it was my custom checkButton) selected in checkedXXXTableViewCell.

Finally i need to change my cellForRowAtIndexPath: function as below.
And it works fine.
Hope it helps you. :)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)getCell:(Entity *)entity cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath identifier:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {
    if (allSelected == 1) {
        return [[CheckedxxxCell alloc] initWithEntity:entity index:indexPath.row reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
        return [[xCell alloc] initWithEntity:entity index:indexPath.row reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
}
```