# mark and unmark static table cell via xcode interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

is it possible to mark and un mark static table cell via xcode interface builder? or I should do it programmatically?

[image]

how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you may have check this but this may answer your question:

[Is it possible to configure a UITableView to allow multiple-selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection)